# Problem upgrading to GWT 2.3.0

Tags: gwt

I'm totally flummoxed by a GWT problem, and have no clue how to interpret the GWT log or how to troubleshoot the problem. I'm working on a fairly trivial template project. I upgraded to GWT 2.3.0 and am now running into the following issue when compiling the module using the maven-gwt-plugin:

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0:compile (default) @ gaewebtemplate ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [stuff.gaegwttemplate.Main, stuff.gaegwttemplate.security.SecurityRequest]
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.activity.Activity'
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.place.Place'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
[INFO]          Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.animation.Animation'
[INFO]             Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
[INFO]                Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CrossSiteIframeLinker'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Unable to load class 'com.google.gwt.core.linker.DirectInstallLinker'
[INFO] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.linker.DirectInstallLinker
```

< Huge stack-trace removed >

```
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
[INFO] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
```

< Huge stack-trace removed >

```
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
[INFO] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
```

The two stack traces and cryptic error messages above is then repeated creating page after page of (as far as I can tell) completely useless log information.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Any idea what logging "strategy" Google is using here :).

Comment: I'm also having this problem while updating from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0, and I verified that both gwt-dev, gwt-user and gwt-servlet are all on the same version. Any one has any clues?

Comment: I also had the same problem moving from 2.3 to 2.4 and the answser from @twelve17 works here too, i.e. all I had to do was modify my pom to ensure that the version of gwt-maven-plugin was at least as new as that of gwt-servlet etc., i.e. I had been using a 2.3 version of gwt-maven-plugin and updated it to 2.4.0.

Answer (score 10):

Gunnar,

I ran into a similar issue. If you are trying to use a GWT SDK newer than the maven plugin, you have to also point the maven plugin to that SDK, like this:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html

Otherwise, I believe the maven plugin will still use the GWT version that matches it (if you were to delete your GWT jars from your maven repo, you could confirm this by seeing it downloading the older version.)

Answer (score 1):

The `DirectInstallLinker` class doesn't appear to be present in GWT 2.3, but I do see it in trunk - are you sure you are using 2.3.0? To get this error, it seems likely that you have at least one copy of something newer than 2.3.0 on your classpath.

GWT 2.3.0 was [released](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/versions.html) on May 2, while the DirectInstallLinker doesn't appear to have been [added to source](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/list?path=/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/core/linker/DirectInstallLinker.java&start=10160) until May 6.

The GWT compiler is using the TreeLogger class, built in to GWT as a way for the compiler and generators to nest debug/error/info messages.

Comment: Thanks Colin. You are absolutely right. I had built trunk locally and installed the artifacts in my Maven repo. My preference would be to continue using trunk since RequestFactory seemed a bit broken in 2.3 (for example, not updated to use the new com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus class). Any pointers that would help me troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - the non-deprecated `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory` class in 2.2 indeed references `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus`. If you are still using the deprecated `com.google.gwt.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory`, you should move to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when upgrading from gwt 2.3 to gwt 2.4.  I was being silly and updated the version on the gwt-user dependency but not on the gwt-dev dependency.  So, check that you aren't also being silly.